# How do I style the "User login" text in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal

I pointed to USER LOGIN word of the User Login block on the front page using Firebug. There is a blue square around the word (USER LOGIN) indicating that it is inside a file called HTML.js. Where is that file on the DRUPAL 6 structure. I want to change this word by changing this file and then I re upload it. Is this possible. I would appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go the whole way and [modify the entire login form](http://www.nicklewis.org/node/845) or you can modify the text specifically. The text you are probably looking for is in the user login block in [root]/modules/user.module (line 743):

```
 $block['subject'] = t('User login');
```

However, there are a few caveats:

1. If you're using a theme other than Garland, this text might not be the text you need to modify.
2. Modifying core is *bad*. If you have to upgrade (and you will), you'll have to reapply this change.

To do things the right way you would need to [create a theme](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7) and style the [login form](http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/amanda-luker/theming-user-login-block). The easiest way would be to copy the Garland theme from [base]/themes to /sites/all/themes, change the .info file and modify it using the techniques in the links above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So there is no html.js involved in this issue. Thanks a lot and I benefited a lot from your instructions. I am learning a lot of secrets about Drupal, it really onle field that need someone to specialize in it.